# Installing Apache 2.4.39 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, troubleshooting

When I try to install Apache 2.4.39 on Windows 10, I receive the following error:

```
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I have tried to find a solution, but I can't find how to fix this problem.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -aon | findstr :80
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    192.168.0.8:50021      23.46.202.149:80       CLOSE_WAIT      9608
  TCP    192.168.0.8:50022      23.46.202.149:80       CLOSE_WAIT      9608
  TCP    192.168.0.8:50025      23.46.202.149:80       CLOSE_WAIT      9608
  TCP    192.168.0.8:50026      23.46.202.149:80       CLOSE_WAIT      9608
  TCP    192.168.0.8:50027      23.46.202.149:80       CLOSE_WAIT      9608
  TCP    192.168.0.8:50028      23.46.202.149:80       CLOSE_WAIT      9608
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `netstat -aon | findstr :80`?

Comment: okay and I just did that now

Comment: Yea, PID 4 is probably the SYSTEM process. Do you need to have Apache running on port 80? Can you configure it to run on a different port, such as 8080?

Comment: I could I cant rember how you do that, but could you tell me and ty in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar with Apache config, but you need to change it from `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080 or some other free port`. There should be a `.conf` file that will hold this.

Comment: Take a look through the [Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html) for configuring.

Comment: got it changed and it's fixed ty for your help

Comment: Great! You should add what you configured as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you have "World web Publishing Service" active in your Services control panel and if it is the case you can Disable if you don't need it.

If it is not the case another common reason could be that Skype is using your port 80. You can disable it by going to `Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connections` and uncheck the box `use port 80 and 443 as alternative` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705033/52879))

Finally you could change the listening port of Apache by modifying the file `httpd.conf` in your Apache environment and change the following lines (from port 80 to 8080, for example).

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
ServerName localhost:8080
```

Look into file, could be that some of those are missing in case ignore them.
You can also use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org). Both simplify Apache installation and give you tools to change the listening port easily.

Comment: `Listen 8080` would also work.